# Adapt the size of a Canvas according to the viewport

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I try to create a Canvas with proposals adapted to the size of the screen

Currently I am using this:

**JS**

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const img = new Image();
img.src = './media/assets.png';
 
const render = function() {
  
context.canvas.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth * 1;
context.canvas.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight * 0.95;

      };
      window.addEventListener("resize", render);
      render();
```

**CSS**

```
* { box-sizing:border-box; margin:0; padding:0; }

html { height:100%; width:100%; }

      body {
        align-content:space-around;
        background-color:#202830;
        color:#ffffff;
        display:grid;
        justify-content:center;
        font-size:1.25em;
        min-height:100%;
        width:100%;
      }
```

However this does not work I have an error **"Context is not defined"**

Is it possible to define these two items directly in the index.css file?

```
context.canvas.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth * 1;
context.canvas.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight * 0.95;
```

Defining the size of the Canvas directly in a render bothers me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have variable that's `context`, in your code you name it `ctx`,
update to:

```
    ...
    ctx.canvas.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth * 1;
    ctx.canvas.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight * 0.95;
    ...
```

you also can set to your canvas directly:

```
    canvas.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth * 1;
    canvas.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight * 0.95;
```

so both are referring to your canvas element

Comment: It works superb well, thank you very much !!   However setting the size like this will not distort the images I count used in my canvas?

Comment: yes, this is possible, so it'd be better to do it from js, I've edited my answer

Comment: Thank you very much again Zac, I add canvas.width .... and canvas.height ... after "img.src ...."?